# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' error

Tags: python

Im having a problem with my code and it says

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

and i'm not sure why. the area of my code that causes this is shown below, all help would be appreciated :D!*Edit the error seems to occur because of the input options, if that helps in any way.

```
Score1 = str(input("what did the first person get in their test the first     time?"))
Score2 = str(input("what did the first person get in their test the second  time?"))
Score3 = str(input("what did the first person get in their test the third time?"))

Score4 = str(input("what did the second person get in their test the first time?"))
Score5 = str(input("what did the second person get in their test the second time?"))
Score6 = str(input("what did the second person get in their test the third time?"))


Score7 = str(input("what did the third person get in their test the first time?"))
Score8 = str(input("what did the third person get in their test the second time?"))
Score9 = str(input("what did the third person get in their test the third time?"))


P1S = [Score1, Score2, Score3]
P2S = [Score4, Score5, Score6]
P3S = [Score7, Score8, Score9]



print ("here are the scores of",Name1,",well done") # defines scores
print(P1S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name1,",Well Done") # makes average of  scores
print(sum(P1S)/float(len(P1S)))

print ("here are the scores of",Name2,",well done") # defines scores
print(P2S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name2,",Well Done") # makes average of scores
print(sum(P2S)/float(len(P2S)))

print ("here are the scores of",Name3,",well done") # defines scores
print(P3S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name3,",Well Done") # makes average of scores
print(sum(P3S)/float(len(P3S)))
```

Comment: I think you have to cast the `Score` inputs to int, they are being interpreted as strings initially

Comment: Can you explain what you want it to do? also, could you reduce your code to be minimal to show the eror?

Comment: I want it so I can use my inputs as numbers to work into a sum

Answer (score 1):

You *explicitely* take care that the things the user inputs are strings:

```
Score1 = str(input("what did the first person get in their test the first     time?"))
```

if you replace `str()` by `int()` or `float()` (depending on what you expect the input to be), your problem should go away, because you'd get a numeric type rather than a `str`ing.

Comment: I now get this problem Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\CUR-FSM\10brierleye$\Computing CA 2\task 3 average.py", line 57, in <module>
    Stu3AVG = (sum(Score3)/float(len(Score3))) #defines the average
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: that line doesn't occur in the code you've posted. Really, you could either a) open up a new Question or b) try to **understand** what the error does. Programming is all about understanding problems, and what you're currently doing is only constantly running to StackOverflow to *report* errors. I recommend really reading the error. It really says what's wrong.

Comment: I would try and show you my whole code but it is too long for the reply, basically I input a name and some values to create an average of the inputted scores, sort the name into alphabetical order and sort the averages into numerical order from highest to lowest, yet it says that the integer inputted is not iterable and I am not sure why :L

Answer (score 0):

Cast the string by default input to an integer so that you can compute average scores:

```
Score1 = int(input("what did the first person get in their test the first time?"))
```

Comment: I keep getting the message: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Are you casting the score? Post your updated code for debugging.

Comment: Are you in Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Score7 = int(input("what did the third person get in their test the first time?"))
Score8 = int(input("what did the third person get in their test the second time?"))
Score9 = int(input("what did the third person get in their test the third time?"))P1S = [Score1, Score2, Score3]
P2S = [Score4, Score5, Score6]
P3S = [Score7, Score8, Score9]
print ("here are the scores of",Name1,",well done") # defines scores
print(P1S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name1,",Well Done") # makes average of scores
print(sum(P1S)/float(len(P1S)))

Comment: python 3.2 I believe69

Answer (score 0):

You can also use map while calculating your score.

```
print ("here are the scores of",Name1,",well done") # defines scores
print(P1S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name1,",Well Done") # makes average of  scores
print(sum(map(int,P1S))/float(len(P1S)))

print ("here are the scores of",Name2,",well done") # defines scores
print(P2S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name2,",Well Done") # makes average of scores
print(sum(map(int,P2S))/float(len(P2S)))

print ("here are the scores of",Name3,",well done") # defines scores
print(P3S)
print ("here is the average score of",Name3,",Well Done") # makes average of scores
print(sum(map(int,P3S))/float(len(P3S)))
```

Also can you please tell how are you providing the inputs.

Comment: I am providing the inputs via manual input, I'm still getting the Int is not iterable problem, even though I define the input as an integer(as I need to use it in an equation later in the code)

Comment: the line number is 56 and the error is that INT is not iterable, I'm not sure why because it worked when I had set values, but now that I've added in a way to input values it has broken