# Python problems with division

Tags: python, calculator

I've been attempting to make a calculator where you enter a number then the calculator divides it by 10 then times it by 4 to work out 40%, then prints the final number.

```
a = input("Enter amount: ")
b = a / 10
c = b * 4
print(c)
```

When I run the code I receive this error message:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254182/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-str-error)

Comment: why would you do math this way? You can just do `a * 0.4` to get 40%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = int(input("Enter amount: "))
b = a / 10
c = b * 4
print(c)
```

the normal input takes input as `string`, you need to convert it to `int`

Comment: Just a quick FYI that if the user were to type in a string (e.g. some words) this will crash.

Comment: yes, then you need check it within try catch block to show the exception? like only numbers are allowed, you can also check the type to be sure its a number or not :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm fairly new to stackoverflow and Python still :D

Answer (score 1):

You should always strive to have the minimum amount of code to accomplish a task. There is no reason to have 3 separate variables to get to your answer.

If you are sure to always be entering an integer you could do a one liner like:

```
print(int(input("Enter amount: ")) * 0.4)
```

However you are not guaranteed an integer from input so you need to have some error checking

Your error is cumming from the fact that `input` always returns a string. You must have an int or a float to do basic math with. So you can accomplish this a few ways.

you can use `int()` on the input statement like `int(input("Enter amount: "))` but you will get an error any time a user types anything other than an int.

The way I would do this is to check if the value of input is an int and then move on.

```
def if_int_get_40_percent():

    try:
        print(int(input("Enter amount: ")) * 0.4)
    except:
        if_int_get_40_percent()

if_int_get_40_percent()
```